# Let $A$ be a ring such that $\#\text{Hom} (\mathbb{Z }[x] / (x ^ 2), A) \ge 2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring such that $\#\text{Hom} (\mathbb{Z }[x] / (x ^ 2), A) \ge2$. Is it possible that the ring $A$ is a domain?

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2), A) & \cong \{ f \in \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[x], A) \mid f(x)^2 = 0 \} \\
& \cong \{ a \in A \mid a^2 = 0 \}
\end{align}$$

So if the cardinality is at least two (note that $0^2 = 0$), then there's an $a \neq 0$ such that $a^2 = 0$. Such an $a$ is a divisor of zero, so $A$ can't possibly be a domain.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. A homomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$ is determined by $f(x+(x^2))$
2. Setting $f(x+(x^2))=0$ does define a homomorphism
3. Let $g$ be a different homomorphism and consider $a=g(x+(x^2))$; then…